# Responder con datos a WEBHOOK

Tags: php7, webhook

espero me puedan ayudar con un problema.

Estoy trabajando con un webhook del cual recibo varios eventos,
en este ejemplo el evento se llama exitoso.
Una vez que tengo ese evento le tengo que responder al webhook con 3 parámetros.
**'{"payable": true,  "min_amount": 50,   "max_amount": 1000, }'**

Estoy comenzado con webhooks y no sé como enviar esa respuesta.

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($body);
http_response_code(200); // Return 200 OK 

if ($data->type == 'exitoso'){

    # Respuesta a enviar a Webhook
    $resp= '{"payable": true,
        "min_amount": 5000,
        "max_amount": 1000000,
        }';

  
}
```

Comment: Prueba con `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode(['payable'=>true,'min_amount'=>5000,'max_amount'=>1000000]);`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Sal por la respuesta, pero no veo en el webhook que me mande una respuesta. Tendrás alguna otra idea.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que `$data->type` es `exitoso`? Parece que en el ejemplo comienza con `inbound_p`. Prueba sin el `if()`.

Comment: Es que el nombre del evento puede cambiar ya que son varios eventos los que pueden ocurrir en el webhook.
Muchas gracias, ya quedo solucionado.  Tu respuesta me ay8udo a depurar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias Sal.
Ya funciono, este es el código que me funciono. Espero que le sea útil.

```
    $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($body);
    http_response_code(200); // Return 200 OK 
    
#Event es un evento de tu webhook, pueden ser varios eventos
#con diferentes nombres.
        if ($data->type == 'Event'){
               
        
                $respuesta ='{
                    "payable": true            
                 }';
        
                $json_string = json_encode($respuesta);  
                echo $respuesta;
                
                
                #iniciamos la Session Curl
                $ch = curl_init();
               # Llamamos a la url a la que se harta la peticion.
                $url = 'https://misitioweb.ocm/webhook.php';
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
                
                
                $resp = ["payable" => true];
                       
                //$resp = json_encode( $resp );
                $resp = http_build_query($resp);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$resp);
                
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                curl_exec($ch);
                
                if ( curl_errno($ch) ){
                         curl_errno($ch);
            }else{
                $decoded=json_decode($response,true); 
                }//else
        
                curl_close($ch);
        
        }// Fin if
```